# How to convert string 24hrs type time into 12hrs time

Tags: ios, swift, nstimeinterval

From response I have set time in String, its contains HH: mm format the task is I have to convert that string into 12hrs time interval with AM and PM in another string to display results

For example "16:36:00.000Z" I want my result like 4:36 PM

Here my sample code:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateValue)

// To convert the date into an HH:mm format
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
 let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
 print(dateString)
```

But unfortunately I'm getting nil in date

Comment: ""hh:mm a" should do it. "hh" for 12 format, and "a" for PM/AM.

Answer (score 2):

do like

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                            16:36:00.000Z
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.sssZ"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateValue)

// To convert the date into an HH:mm format
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a" // or //h:mm a
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
print(dateString)
```